# Infinite sum of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite-dimensional, separable, complex Hilbert space, and let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$ such that $||\mathbf{a}||=||\mathbf{b}||=1$.

Since the set $\mathcal{B}(H)$ of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$ is a Banach Algebra, it makes sense to ask whether an infinite series of bounded operators converges or not.
For instance, let $\mathbf{A}_{n}$ be the sequence of bounded operators defined as:

$$
\mathbf{A}_{n}:=\frac{\imath(-1)^{n}}{n}\left(\mathbf{a}^{n} - \mathbf{b}^{n}\right)
$$
Then, does the series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbf{A}_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\imath(-1)^{n}}{n}\left(\mathbf{a}^{n} - \mathbf{b}^{n}\right)
$$
converges?

I am starting to learn functional analysis, hence, I am not quite sure of my way of reasoning.
However, in order to see if the series converges, I looked at the series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|\left|\mathbf{A}_{n}\right|\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left|\left|\mathbf{a}^{n} - \mathbf{b}^{n}\right|\right|
$$
In general it is $\left|\left|\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{Y}\right|\right|\leq\left|\left|\mathbf{X}\right|\right| + \left|\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|\right|$ and $||X^{n}||\leq\prod_{n}||X||$, thus, I concluded that:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|\left|\mathbf{A}_{n}\right|\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left|\left|\mathbf{a}^{n} - \mathbf{b}^{n}\right|\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\left|\left|\mathbf{a}^{n}\right|\right| + \left|\left|\mathbf{b}^{n}\right|\right|\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{n}
$$
Since the last term is a divergent series I can not say anything.
How should I procede?

Thank You.

**EDIT**
I forgot to write that the sequence $\mathbf{A}_{n}$ is Cauchy, indeed:

$$
||\mathbf{A}_{n}-\mathbf{A}_{m}||\leq||\mathbf{A}_{n}||+||\mathbf{A}_{m}||=\frac{1}{n}||\mathbf{a}^{n} - \mathbf{b}^{n}|| + \frac{1}{m}||\mathbf{a}^{m} - \mathbf{b}^{m}||\leq\frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{m}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $B(H)$ is a Banach algebra it makes perfect sense to talk about questions of convergence. Unfortunately, the sum in question need not converge. Let $v$ be some unit vector in $H$. We can construct a counterexample as follows:

Let $P_v$ denote the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $v$. Let $a = - P_v$. Then $a^{n} = (-1)^{n} P_v$, since $P_v$ is a projection and so idempotent. Let $b$ be the identity operator on $H$.

Next, observe that $$A_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} (a^n - b^n) = \frac{-1}{n} (I - P_v). $$ Then for any $m$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} A_n = - \left( \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n} \right) (I-P_v).$$
If the sum were to converge, then we would have to have that $$
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \left \| \sum_{n=1}^m A_k \right \| = \left \| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_k \right \| < \infty.$$

But by the above
$$ \left \| \sum_{n=1}^m A_k \right \| = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n},$$
which diverges to infinity ($I-P_v$ is the orthogonal projection onto the complement of the span of $v$, and so also has norm $1$). So the sum in question does not converge.

Comment: Or simpler: Let $a$ be the identity, $b=-a$.